# IE11 force sites to run in IE9 or IE10 mode

Tags: group-policy, internet-explorer-11

Is there a way via GPO to have sites run in IE9 or IE10 mode? We have a few sites now that won't run in IE11, but they also won't run when added to compatibility view (IE7). We have one vendor site that strictly only allows IE9 or IE10, nothing else. Becoming a huge PAIN! Clients are mainly Windows 7 Pro, we have 2 Surface Pro3 8.1 clients.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, use Enterprise Mode.

From Microsoft: [What is Enterprise Mode?](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/dn640687.aspx)

You use the [Enterprise Mode Site List Manager](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42501) to create an XML containing the sites that need to be run in Enterprise mode, with appropriate compatibility levels set:

[image]

You then save that file to a network share someplace (we keep ours in a folder inside the domain's NETLOGON folder), and setup the GPO to apply it to machines.

The GPO is "Administrative Templates\Windows Components\Internet Explorer\Use the Enterprise Mode IE website list", we use it at the "User Configuration" level.

More info from MS: [Turn on Enterprise Mode and use a site list](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/dn640699.aspx)

Notes:

- After the list has been updated and put into place (after GP is successfully applied), users need to close all running copies of IE (or log off, or reboot, etc.), and then, a little over 65 seconds after the next time they open IE, the updated list will be applied to them.
- The version currently being used is reported in the client's registry in key "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\EnterpriseMode\CurrentVersion" (this will probably be under HKLM if you use a computer-level GP to apply the list). This will update on-the-fly once the new version is applied (so you can sit and repeatedly hit F5 to refresh until you see it's updated).
- There are TWO versions of the Site List Manager now.  One that does v1 schemas (for IE11 on Win 7, 8 and 10), and one that does v2 schema for use with Edge on Windows 10.  The new list manger says its for Windows 10, but it can be installed and used (to create lists) on a Windows 7 machine, but you can't have both v1 and v2 of the List Manager installed on the same machine.
- One of the options for version 2 and Edge is nice, as it will automatically switch over to using IE11 for sites that are configured to do so.  Makes leaving Edge as the default browser a little more palatable.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. Does this over ride or turn off current CPO compatibility view settings? The one that forces sites to render in IE7?
From the sounds of it, it seems like version 2 of site manager is backwards compatible? So using a list created with version 2 will still function with Windows 7 and 8.1 client correct?

Comment: disregard that last question, just pulled this from the release notes on v2: "Note that this new v.2 schema is not currently supported on Windows 7, Windows 8.1, or Windows 10 Build 10240."